# My discord bot is sending multiple messages at once instead of just one

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and Discord Bots. I am trying to make a simple bot that just copies what a user says and then sends that exact message back. I am having difficulties though because for some reason the bot sends multiple messages at once instead of a singular message.

Here is my code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {

    if (message) {
        var messageArray = message.substring(0).split(' ');
        var recentMessage = messageArray[0];
       
        messageArray = messageArray.splice(1);
        switch(recentMessage) {
            default:
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to:channelID,
                    message: recentMessage
                })
                break;
         }
     }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [discord ping example](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/examples/ping), you can access the contents of the message with [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content). I'm not sure, but you code looks like it is breaking the `message` object apart which might be why you're getting multiple messages back.

You might try changing your code to be:

```
bot.on('message', function (message) {
   // Send message back on the same channel
   message.channel.send(message.content);
});
```

or to reply

```
bot.on('message', function (message) {
   // Reply to message with the same message
   message.reply(message.content);
});
```